# How to bypass scope convention in ruby if else statements

Tags: ruby, if-statement, scope

This shows an error because ruby scope rules prevent me from accessing outer variables inside an if else block.

```
puts "Enter Line 1 m and c:"
m1 = gets.to_f
c1 = gets.to_f

puts "Enter Line 2 m and c:"
m2 = gets.to_f
c2 = gets.to_f

if ((m1==m2) and (c1==c2))
  puts "infinite solutions"
elsif ((m1==m2) and (c1!=c2))
  puts "no solution"
else
  x = (c1 - c2)/(m2 - m1)
  y = m1*x + c1
  puts "(x,y) = (" + x + "," + y+")"
end
```

Can you please tell me a way to get around this error ?

Update:

actually the error i get is: 
undefined local variable or method 'c1' 
for main:Object from :7 
from C;/Ruby200-x64/bin/irb:12;in ''

Comment: Your condition on `elsif` is redundant. `m1 == m2` would suffice.

Comment: What is the scope error that you get? I don't see anything wrong with the scope. The question is not clear.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. One error that http://stackoverflow.com/a/28834277/2597260 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/28834227/2597260 mentioned is in the `puts "(x,y) = (" + x + "," + y+")"`. I have tried code with interpolation it on 2.0.0 (in home) and on a site: http://repl.it/cbg (2.2.0) and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [*interpolation*](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation) to get rid of this.

```
puts "(x,y) = (#{x}, #{y})"
```

You were trying to *concatenate* `String` object with `Float` object. That's not possible, so you have to convert those `Float` to `String` objects before *concatenation*.

*modified code:*

```
puts "Enter Line 1 m and c:"
m1 = gets.to_f
c1 = gets.to_f

puts "Enter Line 2 m and c:"
m2 = gets.to_f
c2 = gets.to_f

if m1 == m2 and c1 == c2
  puts "infinite solutions"
elsif m1 == m2 and c1 != c2
  puts "no solution"
else
  x = (c1 - c2)/(m2 - m1)
  y = m1*x + c1
  puts "(x,y) = (#{x}, #{y})"
end
```

**output**

```
[arup@Ruby]$ ruby a.rb
Enter Line 1 m and c:
14
21
Enter Line 2 m and c:
12
44
(x,y) = (11.5, 182.0)
[arup@Ruby]$
```

Comment: But i still get the same error. This does not do anything to rectify the scope  problem, does it? Also, can you please explain this code snippet? What is interpolation?

Comment: @RahulKejriwal There is nothing _scope_ issue. What was there is _type conversion_ issue.

Comment: actually the error i get is:
undefined local variable or method 'c1' for main:Object 
from <irb>:7 
from C;/Ruby200-x64/bin/irb:12;in '<main>'

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't prevent you from accessing outer variables, the error you see is:

> `+': no implicit conversion of Float into String (TypeError)

which is completely different and has nothing to do with variables visibility scopes. What error says is that you can't sum up `String` and `Float`(try `'a' + 1.0` in console).

To fix it you should convert variables to strings by yourself with:

```
puts "(x,y) = (" + x.to_s + "," + y.to_s + ")"
```

or by using [interpolation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation)(which is preferable):

```
puts "(x,y) = (#{x}, #{y})"
```